# Converting makefile project to CMake

Tags: makefile, cmake

Today, I got a project with a `makefile`  to compile it, but unfortunately I can't run a `makefile` on `Windows`. So I started converting it to `CMake` but as I don't have much knowledge on `makefiles` to correctly understand what the following code tries to do and "emulate" the behavior in `CMake`.

So the code where I have problems is the following one:

```
# -- src and obj List ----------
SRC = $(addprefix ${SRC_PATH}/, $(FILE))
OBJ = $(addprefix ${OBJ_PATH}/, $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(FILE))))

# -- Base rules ----------
$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o : $(SRC_PATH)/%.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

#-----Main rule ----------
$(EXE_PATH)/$(PRODUCT): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(OPTFLAGS) $(CFG) $(INC) $(LIB) -lm

# -- Other stuff ----------
depend:
    makedepend $(CFLAGS) -Y $(SRC)
```

Could some one give me some insights in how to convert this one?, especially, in what `$@`, `$<` and `$^`do?

Thanks.

Comment: you probably want to use Cygwin, it depends on what is your final goal with this

Comment: You can use makefiles on Windows. And you should probably start by reading the GNU make (or whatever make) manual.

Comment: This looks like boilerplate Make code to handle dependencies, which CMake automatically does.  A line-by-line translation will make no sense.  If it's a simple project, all you want is a list of sources, name and location of the output, and the flags for the compiler and the linker.  With those, start a CMakeLists.txt from scratch.  If it's complex, expect to spend some time learning advanced `make` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

`$@`, `$<` and `$^` are automatic variables, relevant documentation can be found [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables)